# Override a page template from a plugin in a child theme

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a plugin which creates a custom post type "projects". In the plugin folder is a template file (single-project.php) where i would like to make some changes. But i'm wondering how i can override this file from the child theme i'm working on. I've tried to make a copy and place it in my child theme folder, but wordpress doesn't pick that one up. How can i achieve this without editing the file in the plugin folder (and risk lose my changes when the plugin is updated?)

Comment: You should ask the plugin's developers. All plugins are different.

Comment: @vancoder No, in that regard they are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [filter `template_include`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/b3b8942dfcb451eddb5559b63c1043fce5d9449e/wp-includes/template-loader.php#L104) to override a template path. Example:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) {
    
    if ( ! is_singular() ) {
        return $template;
    }
    
    if ( 'project' !== get_post_type() ) {
        return $template;
    }
    
    // Now we can safefely
    return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-project.php';      
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked